# Finding a sum of two elements in an array of integers and returning the indexes of first match of two elements, work for some and doesn't work for few

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a question in which we have to traverse array and find the indices of two elements who's some matches with any given value.

I'm running nested for loop through array and parallelly checking the sum of two elements and returning the index of both elements, if it matches answer

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

        int ans[] = new int[2];
        int sum=0;
        int index=0;

myloop: for (index=0; index < nums.length; index++) {
             for (int index2 = index + 1 ; index2 < nums.length - 1; index2++) {
                sum = nums[index] + nums[index2];

                if (sum == target) {
                    ans[0]= index;
                    ans[1]= index2;
                    break myloop;
                }

                sum=0;
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

It is working for few cases and isn't working for few, I'm getting wrong output. Any advice?

Comment: Can you give examples of cases it does and doesn't work for?

Comment: working input :  array > [2,7,11,15]
                         sum > 9

Comment: Is that one it does work for or doesn't?

Comment: not working input :  array > [[3,2,4]
                              sum > 6

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop condition `index2 < nums.length - 1` is incorrect, it should be `index2 < nums.length`. For instance if you are given

```
nums = {1, 2, 3, 4} target = 7
```

your current code

```
for (index=0; index < nums.length; index++) {
   for (int index2 = index + 1 ; index2 < nums.length - 1; index2++) {
       ...
   }
```

will never test `3 + 4`.

Why all these `sum` and `ans`?

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; ++j) 
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) 
        return new int[] {i, j};   // we've found it! Let's return it 

  return new int[0]; // let's return an empty array, not {0, 0} one  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, but even after making those changes it doesn't work.

Comment: @Geek8Work: could you provide a *counter example*, please?

Comment: 1. working input : array > [2,7,11,15] sum > 9, 2. not working input : array > [[3,2,4] sum > 6.   You asked this?

Comment: Please, change inner loop into `for (int index2 = index + 1 ; index2 < nums.length; index2++)`; and `break myloop;` into `return ans;`